# MediaController blocking other ui elements

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am using a ConstantAnchorMediaController as posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881272/extending-mediacontroller-for-android) in order to limit my media controls to a small window where I play my videos. I also use a little padding since the controls somehow seem to be attached to the bottom of the screen.

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoViewSlideShow);

mMedia = new ConstantAnchorMediaController(getActivity(), mVideoView);

mMedia.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
mMedia.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 50);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mMedia);
```

The problem is when the play controls from the mediacontroller are shown, other elements in the screen (I have a few buttons) seem to be blocked; some of them do work (the furthest from the video window) yet they show no UI response (i.e. buttons don't change color when pressed), some don't even work, as though the video controls overlay is "above them" even when it is clearly not (visually, at least).

Hiding the media controls makes all the UI work properly again.